# can't reference non-static method from anonymous method

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-methods

i need to call a non-static method from an async operation ,
for ease i'm using apm design , by defining a delegate assign it an anonymous method 
and calling beginInvoke on it .

to my surprise i could not reference a non-static method from my implementation

any idea why that is ?

```
public delegate void UpdatePlayersLogin(IServerCallback callback, Guid callback_playerId, Player player, List<IServerCallback> toRemove, ManualResetEvent handel);

[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant , InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class ServerService : IServer
{

    UpdatePlayersLogin updateLogin = (callback, callback_playerId, player, toRemove, handle) =>
    {
        try
        {
            callback.PlayerChangedStatus(player);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            RemovePlayer(callback, callback_playerId, toRemove);
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Set();
        }
    };

    .
    .
    private void RemovePlayer(IServerCallback callback, Guid playerId, List<IServerCallback> toRemove)
    { . . . . . . }

    private void NotifyPeersOfClientLogin(Player player)
    {
        . . . . .   
         foreach (var key_CallBackPair in players)
         {
                handels[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                updateLogin.BeginInvoke(key_CallBackPair.Value, key_CallBackPair.Key, player, toRemove, handels[i], null, null);                     
                . . . . .
         }
        ..... 
    }
```

is there a way i could reference the non-static method ?

Comment: Can you show us the enclosing scope?   i.e.  where is the `updateLogin` variable being declared?  Can you show us that method's signature?

Comment: What compiler error do you get?

Comment: @eranotzer: Right, now we've got the context (although the exact compiler error message would have been useful) it looks like my guess was correct. Just assign to the field in a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be fine if the lambda expression itself is within an instance method... but if it's in a static method, then what instance do you expect `RemovePlayer` to be called on?

(As an aside, `update_players_login` is a highly unconventional type name. `UpdatePlayersLogin` would be better.)

EDIT: Okay, my guess is that you're declaring an instance variable, like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    Action action = () => Foo();

    void Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

If that's not the case, please clarify your post, because it's missing important information at the moment.

If that *is* the case, the problem is just that an instance variable initializer can't refer to `this`... but you can initialize it in the constructor instead:

```
class SomeClass
{
    Action action;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        action = () => Foo();
    }

    void Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

I would also make the field `readonly` unless you intend to reassign it somewhere else.

Comment: @eran An instance method is a non-static method.

Comment: @eranotzer: Just as an instance variable? It would have been helpful to say so before. Will edit.

Comment: i realize what an instance method is , i just wanted  to know what 
he meant by declaring it with in it ... 
i declared it in the scope of the class but not in a method.

Comment: @eranotzer: Yes, we know that now - but your post didn't make it clear at all. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints before your next question. The more effort you put into asking a good question, the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.

Comment: well you had it right , 
thanks . 
now i understand what you meant , i didn't realize it had to be initialized in that manner  ,
by the way .. if where on the subject any ideas why i could not declare it in the scope of the class like i would a global variable ?

Comment: @eranotzer: Well that delegate needs to refer to a *specific* instance in order to call the instance method... and just as you can't declare that one instance variable is initialized using the value of another instance variable, you can't use `this` in an instance variable initializer for an anonymous function.