# Async lazy initialization in static class not compiling

Tags: c#

I am attempting to incorporate async lazy initialization in a static class per Stephen Cleary's blog post (http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html):

```
internal static class ThirdPartyCommunicator
{
    private static readonly AsyncLazy<IClient> myClient = new AsyncLazy<IClient>
    (
     async () => { var client = await CreateClient(); return client; }
    );

    private static async Task<IClient> CreateClient()
    {
        var identity = service.GetIdentity();

        await identity.AuthenticationAsync();

        return identity.Client();
    }

   internal static async void DoWork()
   {     
      var client = await this.myClient; //compilation error
      ....
```

In `DoWork()`, I get the error:

> Cannot access static field "myClient" in non-static context

I'm unclear as to what non-static context is causing this issue.

Comment: This might explain things : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539036/cant-reference-non-static-method-from-anonymous-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `static` method cannot use, in any sense, the `this` keyword.  There is no `this` when `static` :)

Delete the `this` keyword and everything will compile fine because myClient is also `static`.

Comment: Wow, and that's what happens when you copy and paste before coffeee.

Comment: Hehe, I often get stumped by the most mundane of issues when working with new concepts or technology, not realising it's a business as usual problem rather than a problem with the pattern I'm working with.